# llc - expected value token error

Tags: llvm

I'm getting this message when I try to llc my example.ll file:

```
llc: example.ll:12:29: error: expected value token
%1 = icmp slt i1 %cmptmp, i16 0
                          ^
```

The example.ll file:

```
; ModuleID = 'modulle'

define i16 @main() {
entry:
  %x = alloca i16
  store i16 2, i16* %x
  br label %loop_condition

loop_condition:                                   ; preds = %loop, %entry
  %0 = load i16, i16* %x
  %cmptmp = icmp sgt i16 %0, 1
  %1 = icmp slt i1 %cmptmp, i16 0
  br i1 %1, label %loop, label %while_continue

loop:                                             ; preds = %loop_condition
  br label %loop_condition

while_continue:                                   ; preds = %loop_condition
  ret i16 0
}
```

When I remove **i16** everything works fine, but I don't know why LLVM insert that in my code. Does anybody know what's the problem?

*--- UPDATE ---*

The .ll output is from my toy compiler. This is the code for lines *11* and *12*:

```
Value *cond = llvm::CmpInst::Create(llvm::Instruction::ICmp, llvm::CmpInst::ICMP_SLT, binRelOpCond, llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::getGlobalContext(), llvm::APInt(16, 0, true)), "", codeGenContext.getBlock());
```

where **binRelOpCond** variable is:

```
CmpInst *compareRes = CmpInst::Create(Instruction::ICmp, CmpInst::ICMP_SGT, left, right, "cmptmp", codeGenContext.getBlock());
```

Thanks.

Comment: "I don't know why LLVM insert that in my code" - could you be more specific? What generated that fauly ll file?

Comment: In my toy compiler, this is the code for that segment: 

`Value *cond = llvm::CmpInst::Create(llvm::Instruction::ICmp, llvm::CmpInst::ICMP_SLT, binRelOpCond, llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::getGlobalContext(), llvm::APInt(16, 0, true)), "", codeGenContext.getBlock());` 

**binRelOpCond** is: 

`CmpInst *compareRes = CmpInst::Create(Instruction::ICmp, CmpInst::ICMP_SGT, left, right, "cmptmp", codeGenContext.getBlock());`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: OK, thanks for including the code, though it's better to edit that into the body of the question :-) I think I see the bug - I updated my answer below accordingly.

Comment: Done. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ll file is malformed. `icmp`'s syntax doesn't have a type for each operand, just a single type for both:

```
<result> = icmp <cond> <ty> <op1>, <op2>
```

Looking at the code you added in the comment which generated the ll, the bug is with `llvm::APInt(16, 0, true)` - you're explicitly creating a constant of type `i16`, but you may only compare with a constant of type `i1` since that's `%cmptmp`'s type. I don't know why no assertion caught that, though.